# Versioning support for Entity Framework auto generated T-SQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a solution which uses Entity Framework model first approach.

The problem I am facing is that whenever I change something on a table, add a column or change a relationship,I right click and go for "Generate Database from Model", which re-generates ALL the code for the solution even if I just changed one table..and that generated code is useless for a production database since it drops every table and then re creates them..

I am wondering, isnt there be an option just to generate the T-SQL with the changes I made ? Otherwise model first would be useless after your app goes into prod.

I am using entity framework 5.0

Comment: If you're on EF5.0, I'd consider [Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would suggest you to use [Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) when you need to sync your databases at Production environment.

This tool helps you to compare and synchronize databases using sync scripts without losing data (it will alert about if so) and its UI is just awesome.